Failed to build React Native app - Could not create provider for value source AndroidLocationsBuildService.AndroidDirectoryCreator
For context, I tried to run a React Native project on my Windows 11 laptop (usually I do it on my Linux PC). The project runs fine on my PC, but it has this error when I try to run it on my laptop:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\<My User Acc>\Documents\<Project Folder>\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Failed to create service 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.AndroidLocationsBuildService_e39ed2c7-9f9c-4315-bc2a-ef27a3dfa2ae'.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.AndroidLocationsBuildService.
         > Could not create provider for value source AndroidLocationsBuildService.AndroidDirectoryCreator.

Here is my build.gradle file:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "35.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 35
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

For added context, here are my Java version:
java version "18.0.2.1" 2022-08-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing)

I tried changing the gradle version multiple times (I forgot which versions I tried), and looking for said error on SO which to no avail.
Any idea?
